# Python multiple threaded servers running in the same program

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

So I am currently writing a python server for a small game. I am currently trying to have the program run two servers in threads. From testing I have found a small bump in my process and that is that only one server is running at a time. I am using different ports for each of the servers however the one connected first takes dominance.
Server code snippets:

```
class loginServer(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        sent = str(self.data,'ascii').split(":")
        print("login:\t\t",sent)
        if (sent[0] == "l"):
            #login check
            #cur.execute("SELECT password, userid FROM `prototb` WHERE username = '"+sent[1]+"'")
            cur.execute("SELECT `displayname`,`curmap`,`curpos`,`Inventory`,`abilities`,`password`,`userid` FROM `prototb` WHERE username = '"+sent[1]+"'")            
            plyInfo = cur.fetchone()#get the information from the database
            if (plyInfo != None):#if the account doesnt exist the username is wrong
                if (plyInfo[5] == sent[2]):#check the correctness of the password
                    print("Login-Success:\t",plyInfo)
                    send = pickle.dumps([plyInfo[1],plyInfo[2],plyInfo[3],plyInfo[4],plyInfo[5]])
                else:
                    self.request.send(bytes("-", 'ascii'))#refuse entry (bad password)
            else:
                self.request.send(bytes("-", 'ascii'))#refuse entry (bad username)

def run_loginServer():
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9000

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9000
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), loginServer)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

And for the other server thread:

```
class podListener(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
        self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
        sent = str(self.data,'ascii').split(":")
        print("pods:\t\t",sent)
        if (sent[0] == "l"):
            maps[mapNum][0] = sent[1]
            maps[mapNum][1] = self.client_address[0]
            maps[mapNum][2] = sent[2]
            print("Pod Connected:\t",maps[mapNum])
            #send confirmation
            self.request.send(bytes("+", 'ascii'))
        else:
            print("Pod Failed connection: ", self.client_address[0])


def run_podListener():
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9001

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9001
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), podListener)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```

Then I run this to start them both:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    #get the database handle
    run_dbConnect()
    #run the map pod server
    run_podLauncher()
    #run the login server ### localhost 9000
    run_loginServer()
```

The client works connecting to them separately, when I comment out the threads individually, but never together. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is a typo in run_podLauncher or run_podListener name. I don't see how you start threads

Comment: ....I know what happened I have a version where there were threads, but it got so messy that I went back to a earlier save. I guess I went far enough back to get rid of my threads, which I missed replacing.

Comment: Well now I'm embarrassed. Thanks for the help. :D